# "a coroutine's promise must declare either 'return_value' or 'return_void'" Error Visual Studio 2019 C++ 20

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20, c++-coroutine

VS2019 latest c++ compiler.

Error is :"a coroutine's promise must declare either 'return_value' or 'return_void'"

Example pulled from David Mazièreshttps://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/blog/c++-coroutines.html blog
that works under a different compiler,GCC 10.2.

I can't get the source code to compile in VS2019.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <coroutine>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
struct ReturnObject {
    struct promise_type {
        ReturnObject get_return_object() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return{}; }
        void unhandled_exception() {}
        
    };
};

struct Awaiter {
    std::coroutine_handle<>* hp_;
    constexpr bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) { *hp_ = h; }
    constexpr void await_resume() const noexcept {}
};

ReturnObject
counter(std::coroutine_handle<>* continuation_out)
{
    Awaiter a{ continuation_out };
    for (unsigned i = 0;; ++i) {
        co_await a;
        std::cout << "counter: " << i << std::endl;
    }
}

void
main1()
{
    std::coroutine_handle<> h;
    counter(&h);                
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        std::cout << "In main1 function\n";
        h();
    }
    h.destroy();
}
```

What am I missing? New to coroutines in C++. Who isn't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both compilers are correct. Flowing off the end of a coroutine when the promise type doesn't have `return_void` is undefined behaviour:

> [*[stmt.return.coroutine]/3*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/stmt.return.coroutine#3):
>
> > If `p.return_­void()` is a valid expression, flowing off the end of a coroutine is equivalent to a `co_­return` with no operand; otherwise flowing off the end of a coroutine results in undefined behavior.

You can define a noop `return_void` in the promise type to get the behaviour you seem to be going for:

```
void return_void() noexcept {}
```

Comment: This is not exactly so. Visual Studio will show you the error even if ```co_­return``` with no operand is present at the end of coroutine, but no ```return_void``` method in the promise exists.

Comment: @Fedor, That's a different case, covered by [\[stmt.return.coroutine\]/2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/stmt.return.coroutine). Compilers are required to error out if you have an explicit `co_return` with no `return_void`.

Comment: Does this mean that the following code would not compile in VS (and exhibits undefined behavior)? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle#Example

Comment: @axxel, At a glance, I think so.

Comment: I tried to 'report' this issue via the 'discussion' page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle. No reaction, yet. No idea if anyone is looking at that page at all...